# Open app from Link Xamarin Forms App links

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to open application from Link, I implemented some steps but didn't work, if anyone have idea about the problem help me, when clicking on this link didn't open application http://amaar-app.com/ar/unit/207

First in android I put this code in MainActivity and SplashActivity

```
   [Activity(Label = "عمار", Icon = "@drawable/icon600",
             Theme = "@style/splashscreen", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
                  DataScheme = "https",
                  DataHost = "amaar-app.com",
                  DataPathPrefix = "/ar/unit",
                  AutoVerify = true,
                  Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
                  DataScheme = "http",
                  DataHost = "amaar-app.com",
                  AutoVerify = true,
                  DataPathPrefix = "/ar/unit",
                  Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

    public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

--

```
[Activity(Label = "عمار", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", 
        MainLauncher = false,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,Exported =true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
                  DataScheme = "https",
                  DataHost = "amaar-app.com",
                  DataPathPrefix = "/ar/unit",
                  AutoVerify = true,
                  Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
                  DataScheme = "http",
                  DataHost = "amaar-app.com",
                  AutoVerify = true,
                  DataPathPrefix = "/ar/unit",
                  Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

in ios I do that
[Enable associated domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX6Xc.png)

in shared project I do that

```
 protected override void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("hi", "hi", "ok");
            });
        }
```

in web configuration

https://amaar-app.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association (for ios)

https://amaar-app.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json (for android)

Comment: I can't open the [link](https://amaar-app.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json) you provided...

Comment: It open JSON object I take steps from this link https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/08/applinks-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: You can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking), it tells how to create App-Linking. It could be helpful to you.